# Filtered unique constraint or similar tool

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to figure out a workaround for a design mistake that it's too late to fix. I basically expect duplicate data coming into a table that's specifically structured to avoid it:

```
CREATE TABLE building (
    building_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    address_id INT NOT NULL,
    company_id INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT building_pk PRIMARY KEY (building_id),
    CONSTRAINT building_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (address_id),
    CONSTRAINT building_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company (company_id)
);
CREATE INDEX building_idx1 ON building (address_id);
CREATE INDEX building_idx2 ON building (company_id);

/* Prevent dupes */
ALTER TABLE building ADD CONSTRAINT building_uk1 UNIQUE (address_id);
```

<sup>*(Original localised names have been changed to make them more clear and relevant to the question.)*</sup>

The *export buildings* API at Acme Inc. will be sending different buildings that share the same address. Removing `building_uk1` would break certain features that assume uniqueness and we can't afford a major rewrite at this point.

I'd like to evaluate the effects of disabling `building_uk1` just for the aforementioned company (`company_id=314`), which may do without the features that depend on uniqueness. What are my options to relax `building_uk1` and only enforce it when `company_id` is not 314?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple unique [filtered index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/cc280372.aspx) should be enough:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_building_uk1] ON [dbo].[building]
(
    [address_id] ASC
)
WHERE (company_id <> 314)
```

Comment: Documentation is not very clear about supported versions but it appears to work fine in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, it definitely works in 2008. I'm using it in several places in our system. It looks like MS removed docs for 2008 from MSDN after release of 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by check constriant, Let me see whether I understood your requirement correct

Creating a function which will check distinct if it is not building_id 314

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckDistinctConstraint ()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @retValue int = 0
  DECLARE @cnt int = 0
  DECLARE @distcnt int = 0
  SELECT
    @cnt = COUNT(*),
    @distcnt = COUNT(DISTINCT address_id)
  FROM building
  WHERE company_id <> 314
  IF @cnt <> @distcnt
  BEGIN
    SET @retValue = 1
  END
  RETURN @retValue
END
```

Add constraint by applying this function

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Building
  ADD CONSTRAINT CheckDistConstraint CHECK (dbo.CheckDistinctConstraint() =0);
```

Create table scripts

```
CREATE TABLE building (
    building_id INT  NOT NULL,
    address_id INT NOT NULL,
    company_id INT NOT NULL--,
    CONSTRAINT building_pk PRIMARY KEY (building_id)--,
    --CONSTRAINT building_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES address (address_id),
    --CONSTRAINT building_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company (company_id)
);

--inserts successfully
insert into building ( building_id, address_id, company_id) values
(1,11,22)

--insert failed bcos check constraint
insert into building ( building_id, address_id, company_id) values
(5,11,315)

-- insert successfull eventhough duplicate in address_id but building_id is 314
insert into building ( building_id, address_id, company_id) values
(311,11,314)
```

Not sure you are looking something like this?

Comment: I want an exception when `company_id=314`, not `building_id=314`. But I understand your approach nevertheless. About performance, this will run the query in the function once per row on insert and update, am I correct?

Comment: Yes you can check by providing examples

Comment: Yes it works as every other check constraint, regarding performance we can find a way for tuning the function

Comment: Updated my script to check Company_id

Comment: [Be careful with constraints calling UDFs](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/12/17/be-careful-with-constraints-calling-udfs.aspx)

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Pretty good info. Although I think it wouldn't matter in my case (there's no GUI or code that ever updates `company_id` and a manual update in DB would break many other things) it's not as robust as it should.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, if filtered index is enough for your purposes, use it. It will always be correct and its performance would most likely be better than UDF. It may also help with certain queries that have the same `WHERE` condition as the index. Only if the logic of the constraint is too complicated, then consider other methods, like triggers and UDFs in constraints.